# How can I tell whether a skill is a "default weapon attack"?

Tags: grim-dawn

I'm playing Grim Dawn using a Shaman/Soldier classes.  I'm using Primal Strike and Thunderous Strike (so I get lightning strikes on every attack).

I also had points in:

- Brute Force
- Feral Hunger
- Upheaval

But someone pointed out to me that I'm wasting my points in Feral Hunger and Upheaval, because they only work in conjunction with "default weapon attacks", and Thunderous Strike isn't a default weapon attack.

Up till now I had assumed that any passive skill (marked with a circle) works with any active skill (marked with a square), but that seems not to be the case.  When I'm choosing skills, is there a way I can tell whether given passive and active skills will work together?

I did find this page...

https://grimdawn.gamepedia.com/Default_weapon_attack_replacer_skills

...which seems to indicate that there are almost *no* primary weapon skills with which I can use these passive skills.  Is that right?  If so, how can I best tailor my character to use passive skills (or avoid them if they'll be useless)?

Comment: Consider to link skills, using [calculator](https://www.grimtools.com/calc/eZPMj1PN), where you highlight skills in question. It would be easier to answer. And btw, try to mouseover `Thunderous Strike` (in calculator or in game), you will be suprised.

Comment: I feel like it's very easy to put points in a lot of skills without realizing that some of them will never trigger.  I'm looking for an answer that explains how this works and gives examples of attacks that _aren't_ "default weapon attack" and skills that wouldn't work with them, vs. attacks that _are_ "default weapon attack" that can be combined with these passive skills that only trigger on default weapon attacks.  Some Google searching reveals that I'm far from the only one who finds this confusing.

Comment: You can avoid this situation if use one of proven to work builds. It's anyway more efficient  time-wise (consider how much time you need to play yourself until you are able to combine all this knowledges regarding skills synergies, gear and other stuff) and is guaranteed to work in the end-game. Game is unlikely to be balanced so that any skill will do.

Comment: Given that I can respec at any time (albeit with a cost), I'd rather invent my own strategies than just play the way somebody else tells me to play.  If I want to do _that_, I can just watch a stream or something.  I just want to understand this game mechanic.

Comment: I gather any skill that can be assigned to the left or right button is _not_ a "default weapon attack" unless the description specifically says that it counts as a default weapon attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of skill you're looking for is called a Default Attack Replacer (DAR).  **You can tell if a skill is a DAR by checking its description tooltip - if it's a DAR, it will include the phrase "When used as your default weapon attack..."**

The full list of DARs in the game (not including your character's default attack) is:

- Cadence (from Soldier)
- Savagery (from Shaman)
- Fire Strike (from Demolitionist)
- Righteous Fervor (from Oathkeeper)
- Belgothian's Strikes (from [Belgothian’s Slaughter](https://www.grimtools.com/db/itemsets/124) set)
- Touch of Chaos (from [Rah’Zin’s Torment](https://www.grimtools.com/db/itemsets/151) set)
- Fleshwarped Strikes (from [Heart of Theodin Marcell](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/11323))
- Runic Bolts (from [Runebinder’s Spellthrower](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/8756))
- Troll Rage (from [Mistborn Talisman](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/1472))
- Beronath’s Fury (from [Shard of Beronath](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/2888))

Only DARs (and default attack) can trigger Weapon Pool Skills (WPS), attack modifiers that proc off of autoattacks.  You can tell if a skill is a WPS via its tooltip as well; **WPS will include the phrase "X% Chance to be Used."**

Note that most procs on items (phrased "X% Chance on Attack") are *not* WPS, though they look similar.  For instance, the Direwolf Claw skill on [Mythical Direwolf Crest](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/8954) is a WPS, while the Bear Claw skill on [Mythical Sigil of the Bear King](https://www.grimtools.com/db/items/8952) is not.

You can read more detail on how these two skill types interact in [this guide](https://forums.crateentertainment.com/t/turbo-charge-your-auto-attacks-with-default-attack-replacers-and-wps/49376).

Comment: Is Cadence _always_ a DAR, or only on every 3rd hit when it triggers?

Comment: @Kyralessa It is a DAR *except* on every 3rd hit when it triggers.  That is, the "charge-up" attacks can proc WPS, but the big "payoff" hit cannot.

Comment: "The full list of DARs in the game"...shouldn't Thunderous Strike (or Primal Strike + Thunderous Strike) be in the list?

Comment: Or is the idea that a DAR is something that _can_ be used with those skills such as Feral Hunger?  But if so, what (instead of "DAR") are skills like Thunderous Strike called?

Comment: Primal Strike using Thunderous Strike (and similar things like Blade Arc, or Forcewave using Tremor) are not DARs; the term "DAR" exists to distinguish things that work basically like your autoattack (and work with WPS) from things that don't (like Thunderous Strike etc.).  There's not really an official term for stuff like Thunderous Strike - you could call them "zero-cooldown attack-like spells" but that's just a description.  You might find the bottom part of [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Grimdawn/comments/gyjpcj/a_noob_being_confused_about_the_mechanics_of/ftbaray/) helpful.

Comment: And yes, as the answer states, DAR is the term for skills that *can* trigger WPS (like Feral Hunger).

Comment: Thanks, I read it...  But what are PRM, DoT, and OA?

Comment: Panetti's Replicating Missile, Damage over Time, and Offensive Ability.  Those parts of the comment will make more sense if you read the [parent thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Grimdawn/comments/gyjpcj/a_noob_being_confused_about_the_mechanics_of/) that I was answering, but it's mostly just the bottom part (after "what constitutes an "attack" in Grim Dawn?") that pertains to your question about DARs here.

Comment: So if my understanding is finally correct: Most skills are *not* default weapon attacks. Blade Arc, for example, isn't a default weapon attack. But a DAR, even though it's a specific skill, works the same way as a default weapon attack and triggers weapon pool skills. Meanwhile, some non-DAR skills *allow* default weapon attacks, due to recharge time (Primal Strike) or due to the skill not firing on every hit (Cadence). The warning about Thunderous Strike is intended to indicate that while Primal Strike allows default weapon attacks, Thunderous Strike doesn't because it fires every time.

Comment: And then I found a page pointing out that Blade Arc *can* allow weapon pool skills if Clean Sweep is added, because then it has a charge time during which the weapon pool skills can be triggered.  This makes sense according to my understanding above.

Comment: So basically for weapon pool skills to trigger, either (a) you need to use the default attack, or your main skill has to (b) have a cooldown period, or (c) in some other way, like Cadence, allow for some default attacks, or (d) be one of the special exceptions you note above: Savagery, Fire Strike, Righteous Fervor, etc.

Comment: That's all basically correct.  The only quibble is that I'd consider (b) to be just a special case of (a), because what's actually going on with cases like Clean Sweep is that if you put a skill with a cooldown (*any* cooldown skill, its properties and status as an "attack" don't matter) on your left click, and try to use the skill while it's on cooldown, your character will perform a default attack instead.  That default attack will behave like any other default attack, including triggering WPS.

Answer (score 1):

As comments are ephemeral, I wanted to add my own summary answer from the discussion above:

The question is when **weapon pool skills** can be triggered.  Examples of weapon pool skills are Markovian's Advantage, Zolhan's Technique, Belgothian's Shears, and Feral Hunger.  These all have text indicating that they **activate off of default weapon attacks**.

Weapon pool skills can only be triggered in these cases:

- You attack with the **default attack**.
- You attack with a **default attack replacer** (see the list in the other answer).
- You attack **during the cooldown** while using a skill with a cooldown, such as Forcewave, or Primal Strike *without* Thunderous Strike, or Blade Arc *with* Clean Sweep.
- You attack during a **non-triggering hit** using a skill that for other reasons doesn't trigger every time.  For example, Cadence only triggers on every third hit.  The first and second "non-Cadence" hits will trigger weapon pool skills.